# How can I turn a JSONArray into a JSONObject?

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

Basically I have:

```
JSONArray j = new JSONArray();
j.add(new JSONObject()); //JSONObject has a bunch of data in it
j.add(new JSONArray());  //JSONArray has a bunch of data in it
```

And now I would like to turn that `JSONArray` into a `JSONObject` with the same information in it.  So that I can pass around the Object and then when I want I can grab all the information out of the object.  Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Well I tried using JSONArray.toJSONObject(arg) but im new to JSON I couldn't figure it out what the api wanted to put in for the arg.  http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html#toJSONObject(net.sf.json.JSONArray)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Typically, a Json object would contain your values (including arrays) as named fields within. So, something like:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
// populate the array
jo.put("arrayName",ja);
```

Which in JSON will be {"arrayName":[...]}.

Comment: Yep that's what I needed to do instead of just adding my values to an array I just added them to an object and gave each a name identifier.  Thank you.

Comment: What if the there is no "arrayName" ?

Answer (score 3):

I have JSONObject like this: `{"status":[{"Response":"success"}]}`.

If I want to convert the JSONObject value, which is a JSONArray into JSONObject automatically without using any static value, here is the code for that.

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj2=new JSONObject();
obj2.put("Response", "success");
array.put(obj2);
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj.put("status",array);
```

Converting the JSONArray to JSON Object:

```
Iterator<String> it=obj.keys();
        while(it.hasNext()){
String keys=it.next();
JSONObject innerJson=new JSONObject(obj.toString());
JSONArray innerArray=innerJson.getJSONArray(keys);
for(int i=0;i<innerArray.length();i++){
JSONObject innInnerObj=innerArray.getJSONObject(i);
Iterator<String> InnerIterator=innInnerObj.keys();
while(InnerIterator.hasNext()){
System.out.println("InnInnerObject value is :"+innInnerObj.get(InnerIterator.next()));


 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("a");

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    array.put(list.get(i));
}
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

try {
    obj.put("result", array);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you originally get the data as a JSONObject?

Perhaps parse the string as both a JSONObject and a JSONArray in the first place?
Where is the JSON string coming from?

I'm not sure that it is possible to convert a JsonArray into a JsonObject.

I presume you are using the following from [json.org](http://www.json.org/java/)

- [JSONObject.java](http://www.json.org/java/org/json/JSONObject.java)
  A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs. Its external form is a string wrapped in curly braces with colons between the names and values, and commas between the values and names. The internal form is an object having get()  and opt() methods for accessing the values by name, and put() methods for adding or replacing values by name. The values can be any of these types: Boolean, JSONArray, JSONObject, Number, and String, or the JSONObject.NULL object.
- [JSONArray.java](http://www.json.org/java/org/json/JSONArray.java)
  A JSONArray is an ordered sequence of values. Its external form is a string wrapped in square brackets with commas between the values. The internal form is an object having get() and opt() methods for accessing the values by index, and put() methods for adding or replacing values. The values can be any of these types: Boolean, JSONArray, JSONObject, Number, and String, or the JSONObject.NULL object.