# GSON - Convert a list of dynamic entities to JsonObjects

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to convert a list of "dynamic entities" to a JsonObject with GSON. The reason why I'm calling it "dynamic entities" is because the program does not know what he's converting. I'm not able to write serializable objects or convert the JSON to a class by `Gson.toJson()`.

When I try to convert a single object to a JsonObject, it works.

> This is my JSON:
>   https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a94dcefbdbe49d275778b4d8dcc095b2

This is the code I'm executing:

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
```

I will receive an error on the second line with the following content:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [{"gameCategoryId":{"type":"D","value":1},"gameCategoryName":{"type":"D","value":"Slotmachines"},"games":[{"type":"R","entityName":"Game","listOfKeyValuePairs":{"gameId":3}},{"type":"R","entityName":"Game","listOfKeyValuePairs":{"gameId":4}}]},{"0":{"gameCategoryId":{"type":"D","value":1},"gameCategoryName":{"type":"D","value":"Slotmachines"},"games":[{"type":"R","entityName":"Game","listOfKeyValuePairs":{"gameId":3}},{"type":"R","entityName":"Game","listOfKeyValuePairs":{"gameId":4}}]},"gameCategoryId":{"type":"D","value":2},"gameCategoryName":{"type":"D","value":"Tafelspellen"},"games":[{"type":"R","entityName":"Game","listOfKeyValuePairs":{"gameId":5}},{"type":"R","entityName":"Game","listOfKeyValuePairs":{"gameId":6}}]}]

**Question:** How do I convert this JSON to a JsonObject with GSON?

Comment: You are trying to parse to an object but your json is an array.

Comment: I know, but how do I go from the array to a JsonObject? Because I need the JsonObject's entrySet.

Comment: You have to re-think your question and understand the response is not a JSON object, but a JSON array. How would you suggest an idea of transforming an array to an object? Just to iterate over it as if it had a property set? Well you already have it: `JsonArray` is an `Iterable<JsonElement>` so you can simply "foreach" it. All you have to do is: `for ( final JsonElement e : jsonParser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray() ) { }`.

Comment: Yep you are right. But all my code was based on a JsonObject, so I had to think of a way to change the array to a JsonObject. I used this answer to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7193753/4653908 ... Anyway, thanks for the help :D

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot do it at least with a solid rationale behind it: why not just rethink your approach and accept `JsonElement` is the root of JSON objects hierarchy? `JsonElement` is the base class for nulls, primitives, objects and arrays. How would you pretend that an array is an object and vice versa? No way. Just rethink your approach. Also, the question you have linked as the solution is just not Gson at all, and uses `JSONObject` as the root type as well as Gson uses its `JsonElement`. Simply speaking Gson `JsonElement` _is_ that library `JSONObject`.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Urgh you're right. I managed to fix it now though thanks to your previous comment. If you'd like to answer I'll accept that and upvote it :)