# Convert from ResultSet to JSON Object

Tags: java, json, resultset

I am trying to convert ResultSet to JSON object. I managed to get a JSON Array object already. Is there a way I can convert JSON object to JSON Array, or from ResultSet to JSON Object directly?

I tried to follow below suggestions in below link.
[How can I turn a JSONArray into a JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193599/how-can-i-turn-a-jsonarray-into-a-jsonobject/7193753)

But the JSON object I get now is like this:

```
{"data":[{"patient_key":80},{"eng_surname":"CAN"},{"eng_givename":"NOT"}....]}
```

I wish to have something like this for API calls:

```
{       "patientKey": 88,
        "hkid": " U0500574",
        "engSurname": "CAN",
        "engGivename": "NOT ", ....}
```

Is there any way I can get my desired result?

This is how I converted to JSON Array.

```
public static JSONArray convertToJSONArray(ResultSet resultSet)
            throws Exception {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int total_rows = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                        .toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
                jsonArray.put(obj);
            }
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed two lines of your function in the question. Please tell me if it works. then i can tell you what was the problem!

```java
    public static JSONArray convertToJSONArray(ResultSet resultSet)
            throws Exception {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            int total_rows = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
                obj.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                        .toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i + 1));

            }
            jsonArray.put(obj);
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is working! Seems like simply just moving out the JSONObject from the for loop, and add that to the output array in the final step will help!

Comment: Yes. The problem was that when evere you try to add a new field to you json object, it creates a new objects.  So i managed to create object outside the loop, and add it to array after all iterations for adding fields is completed.

Comment: Should `total_rows` be instead `total_columns`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation -

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

public class ResultSetConverter {
  public static JSONArray convert( ResultSet rs )
    throws SQLException, JSONException
  {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

    while(rs.next()) {
      int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      for (int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
        String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);

        if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.ARRAY){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BIGINT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BLOB){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getBlob(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.DOUBLE){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getDouble(column_name)); 
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.FLOAT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getFloat(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.INTEGER){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.VARCHAR){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.TINYINT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.SMALLINT){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.DATE){
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getDate(column_name));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP){
        obj.put(column_name, rs.getTimestamp(column_name));   
        }
        else{
         obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
        }
      }

      json.put(obj);
    }

    return json;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this just converting to JSONArray?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model for the result and convert it into a JSON string. using the GSON class.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(user);
```

[How to convert Java object to JSON String - Gson Java/JSON Serialization Example](https://www.java67.com/2017/05/how-to-convert-java-object-to-json-using-Gson-example-tutorial.html)

take  the above reference. you can parse it into any object.

If you are using java8 use streams for list manipulation

[Stream In Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-in-java/)

Comment: I'm checking this method too. However, since there are chances that some fields might be null. Would that be an issue?

Comment: I managed to modify my current method to convert ResultSet to JSONObject. However, I'm hitting another issue. I need to add another ResultSet into a current JSONObject. I tried to use `.put` method, but it is giving me this:
`"patientPhones":[{"phone_id":42}, {"phone_type_cd":"O"},{"country_cd":"852"},...`
What I need is this:
`"patientPhones": [{"phoneId": 88, "phoneTypeCd": "H",...`
How should I do? Hope you can understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If using a third party library for this is an option, you could use [jOOQ's JSON export capabilities](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/exporting/exporting-json/). You don't have to use the entirety of jOOQ to make use of that, just write:

```java
// Keep this logic
try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {

    // ctx is the jOOQ DSLContext.
    // Optionally pass a JSONFormat parameter to get a different desired output
    System.out.println(ctx.fetch(rs).formatJSON(jsonFormat));
}
```

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)